# Android app is crashing with An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android

Not able to set the data in the database in server...getting values from editText and passing them in doBackground() but error occured while executing in background...any help will be appreciated...thanx in advance...log added......

Here is the log

```
9 10:27:05.333 3245-3523/com.amar.schooladmin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #7
                                                                Process: com.amar.schooladmin, PID: 3245
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                                    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:703)
                                                                    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:145)
                                                                    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:458)
                                                                    at com.amar.schooladmin.AddRecord$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(AddRecord.java:77)
                                                                    at com.amar.schooladmin.AddRecord$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(AddRecord.java:61)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

01-19 10:27:0

> MainActivity.java

```
 button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            roll=editText.getText().toString();
            name=editText2.getText().toString();
            address=editText3.getText().toString();
            fname=editText4.getText().toString();
            mname=editText5.getText().toString();
        }
    });
}

public class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        List<NameValuePair> parms = new ArrayList<>();
        parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("roll", roll));
        parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address));
        parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
        parms.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mname", mname));

        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", parms);

        try {
            int success= jsonObject.getInt("TAG SUCCESSFULLY");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(AddRecord.this, ""+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Add your Error log also in the question

Comment: error log can us to identify problem post your log

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: When you are doing getText().toString(), do it before executing CreateNewProduct or do getText().toString() inside the doInBackground. As I hope indide your parms your values are null and instead of creating the Toast cal e.printStackTrace();

Comment: @RakshitNawani tried both ways but same problem is still occuring

Comment: @VineshChauhan logcat added

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are showing `Toast` in `doInBackground()`. try this

```
 ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(AddRecord.this, ""+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Perfect. @Alex so point whenever you want to perform any operation while in doInBackground(), you have to do it on runnable thread, or else do it in onProgressUpdate or in onPostExecute() methods

Answer (score 1):

You can't write show() method of Toast in doInBackground() because it is not UI thread it is worker thread. You can write Toast in onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

`Toast` is causing the crash to occur, because `Toast` requires UI Thead to display and currently it is in background thread.

Also, you are getting exception at

```
int success= jsonObject.getInt("TAG SUCCESSFULLY");
```

and hence in catch `Toast` line is getting executed.

Please check if `TAG SUCCESSFULLY` key exists in jsonObject or not. Use

```
if(jsonObject.has("TAG SUCCESSFULLY"))
    success= jsonObject.getInt("TAG SUCCESSFULLY");
```